# Problem importing matplotlib.mlab and .pyplot in python 2.7 on Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: python, matplotlib, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to plot a histogram using matplotlib in Python 2.7 on OSX 10.6

I have verified that I can import numpy, scipy, and matplotlib into python. A sample script on the matplotlib website does

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

However, I get an error when doing this. Here is what happens when I try to import mlab.

```
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mlab.py", line 151, in <module>
    import matplotlib.nxutils as nxutils
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/nxutils.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/nxutils.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong that I can't import these as the script does?

Comment: A related issue: If I try to call matplotlib.pyplot.hist() it doesn't work and gives me an AttributeError saying matplotlib has no attribute 'pyplot', but this is listed in the matplotlib documentation.

Answer (score 3):

For the *ImportError*: It seems that there is an architecture mismatch.  Maybe you have installed a 32-bit version of matplotlib, but are using a 64-bit Python?  What does the following shell command print?

```
file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/nxutils.so
```

For the *AttributeError*: You have to explicitely import `matplotlib.pyplot`, it won't get imported automatically when just importing `matplotlib`.  The most common aliasing scheme is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then you can draw your histogram using the `plt` name:

```
plt.hist(...)
```

Comment: I think you are correct. I looked into it a little and apparently I am running 64-bit Python. The output from your question is:
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/nxutils.so: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/nxutils.so (for architecture ppc): Mach-O bundle ppc
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/nxutils.so (for architecture i386): Mach-O bundle i386`

Comment: Is the best option to run python as 32-bit? How would I do this?
I also tried looking for a 64-bit matplotlib, but it seemed that to do this for snow leopard is somewhat involved.