# Matplotlib - Python Error

Tags: python, matplotlib, 64-bit

Setup:

Processor : `x86_64` 
Operating System: `GNU/Linux`
Distro: `Fedora Release 13 (Goddard).`

`Python 2.6.4`

```
 /usr/bin/python
```

Here is the following issue:

I am trying to generate a few graphs using Matplotlib and Python. As I hear from a majority of the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157330/problem-importing-matplotlib-mlab-and-pyplot-in-python-2-7-on-mac-osx-10-6)[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157330/problem-importing-matplotlib-mlab-and-pyplot-in-python-2-7-on-mac-osx-10-6).. there seem to be compatibility issues between matplotlib and 64bit architectures.

I have installed Matplotlib from [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#installing-from-source)

Here is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot-thread-characterization.py", line 24, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 78, in <module>
    new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 25, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py", line 10, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import gtk, FigureManagerGTK, FigureCanvasGTK,\
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 8, in <module>
    import gtk; gdk = gtk.gdk
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    _init()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 52, in _init
    _gtk.init_check()
RuntimeError: could not open display
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is a linking issue but sounds like it can't create the GTK display. Are you running an X11 server or are you running this over ssh for example?

Comment: I am running this over a SSH. 

I am not using the `ssh -X` option.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

matplotlib is failing to connect to any X server for its GTK display.

There are a couple of options here:

1. Run a local X server and enable X11 forwarding in your ssh client, to display the output on your local machine. You can verify this is working by checking that the $DISPLAY environment variable is set on the server.
2. Call matplotlib.use(...) to specify a different display back-end, for example rendering to pdf file, *before* importing pyplot, e.g.

   `import matplotlib as mpl`

   `mpl.use('Agg')`

   `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

See http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#generate-images-without-having-a-window-appear for more details.

Comment: Thanks. In cases where you've `X11 connection rejected, wrong authentication`... The second option can quite useful.

Comment: The second solution worked to me when trying to use matplotlib in a cgi.

Comment: The second solution also helped me out a lot when trying to get things to work on windows.