# What does this (matplotlib) error message mean?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Display is the module:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')   #TkAgg is quite slow but should work on all platforms.

import time
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

def display_2d_array(arr):
    '''Display a square 2D numpy array as a greyscale image.'''
    assert len(arr.shape) == 2 and arr.shape[0] == arr.shape[1]
    plt.ion()
    plt.clf()
    plt.imshow(arr,origin="lower",extent=[0,arr.shape[0],0,arr.shape[0]])
   plt.gray()
   plt.draw()
   raw_input('Hit enter to continue.')
```

But when I call it in a module I get:

```
File "/Users/tomkimpson/display.py", line 8, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site                  packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 26, in <module>
from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 24, in <module>
import matplotlib.artist as martist
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 7, in <module>
from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 35, in <module>
from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/matplotlib/_path.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/matplotlib/_path.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Anyone any idea what this means?!

Comment: It doesn't seem like the function is at all relevant. The error happens at the last import. You can [edit] the question to remove irrelevant code and also provide a more informative title.

Comment: It looks like you may have a problem with your matplotlib installation.  Have you successfully used matplotlib before or did this error just randomly start appearing?  You might try reinstalling matplotlib.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try reinstalling. Never used matplotlib before. Complete programming noob!

Comment: FWIW -- I recently installed matplotlib successfully on OS-X 10.5.8 using `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running this on OS X. Take a look at this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157330/problem-importing-matplotlib-mlab-and-pyplot-in-python-2-7-on-mac-osx-10-6), where another OS X user had your same error. Your matplotlib install is probably corrupted. The marked answer in question linked to [this page](http://telliott99.blogspot.com/2011/07/matplotlib-on-os-x-lion-revised.html), which details how to install matplotlib on OS X.